# Only allow http and SSH traffic

Tags: iptables

I ran the below. What I expected was to be able to browse websites without issues. No sites work and I have no idea what. When I executed `iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT` it works so I'm assuming I missed an OUTPUT rule.

```
iptables -F
iptables -X

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: 2 things off the bat. DNS (primarily) uses UDP, not TCP. `-i` doesn't work on the `OUTPUT` chain. You should have gotten an error.

Comment: @Patrick you should post an answer, probably.